# C# RSA Decryption with Public Key - Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I need to be able to encrypt a small hash in PHP and later decrypt it in C# to compare the hash with the data. So yes, it's being used as a signature to verify the origin of the data.

What I am having trouble with is
(A) Loading the key
(B) Decrypting with public key

With `RSACryptoServiceProvider` I can load the key simply enough, however it doesn't support decryption with the public key.

I've tried with Bouncy Castle, however I can't find any simple examples which show how to load a key and decrypt.

I can get copies of the key in any of the following formats:

```
CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW
CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1_RAW
CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_OPENSSH
CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1
```

My PHP code for encryption is simple enough and working happily.

```
<?php
include 'PHPSecLib/Crypt/RSA.php';
$privatekey = file_get_contents('privatekey.txt');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
$cipher = $rsa->encrypt("simple hash");
file_put_contents('cipher.txt', ($cipher));
```

All I need in C# is a simple way to

- Loading the public key from a string/file from any of the previously mentioned formats or the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` XML format.
- Decrypting with loaded public key

I've been trying for more than a day now and need help with this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are trying to verify a signature using RSA. So that should be what you search for. Here are a few links that show how:

- [Verifying Signatures in .NET.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/201yh4c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Discussion of RSA signature verification in .NET and BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822635/rsa-signing-and-verification-with-c-bouncycastle-and-imported-rsa-key-working)
- [More RSA sign/verify discusion for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437288/signing-and-verifying-signatures-with-rsa-c-sharp)