# Sign a string against an RSA Public Key

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I'm using C# and I'm trying to sign a string with a key produced from the PuTTY Key Generator. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing because I can't see how to import a key into the RsaEngine

I looked at the following:

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter key = new RsaKeyParameters(false, ???, ???);
RsaEngine rsa = new RsaEngine();
rsa.Init(true, key);
```

but it seems that RsaKeyParameter and AsymmetricKeyParameter take a modulus and a exponent which I don't know how to get from my already generated key? I could be using the wrong class though so if anyone has any pointers on this that would be excellent

I looked at: [RSA signing and verification with C#,BouncyCastle and imported RSA key - Working Python example and non-working C# code sample inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822635/rsa-signing-and-verification-with-c-bouncycastle-and-imported-rsa-key-working) but answer has a non existent function:

```
ConvertToRSAPrivateKey
```

Comment: Always specify some tags with a higher amount of followers, otherwise your question will fly "under the radar".

Comment: @JamieH, have you tried looking at RSACryptoServiceProvider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata(v=vs.110).aspx)?
RsaEngine in BC looks way too low level for the generic 'i need to sign data' requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can first [convert the PuttyGen keys into OpenSSH compatible keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use) and then convert this well documented format to C#.

The best I can come up with is [this class of the SSH.NET library code](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/PrivateKeyFile.cs).

In the mean time, please note that you are better off generating the key in the actual library that you want to use. Key formats, especially *private key* formats, are not always compatible.

Comment: Warning: I haven't actually tried above solution. Please indicate success.